# Order Date is correct on the order itself in Admin but incorrect in the Order Confirmation Email (it shows exactly 7 hours more)

Tags: date, time

The orders show the correct Order date in Admin but incorrect Order date (time) on the Confirmation Email. The time on the Confirmation Email is exactly (to the second) 7 hours more.

An example:

Order Date in Admin (this is correct):  Jan 26, 2016 **8:38:29 AM**

Order Date on the Order Confirmation Email (incorrect): Placed on January 26, 2016 **3:38:29 PM**

Any ideas? :-)

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party integrations for email?

Comment: SendGrid - does that make a difference?

Comment: I've never used SendGrid, but it sounds like the issue is with server time somewhere down the line. If it's using an external server to send the emails, it could be using that server time vs your store server's time. If it's still going through your server, there's probably a setting for time offset somewhere in the SendGrid config.

Comment: the time in the Sengrid portal shows correctly - it's only inside the Order Confirmation where it is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is due to the timezone: Your store might be in the GMT-7 timezone, and the date in the order confirmation is UTC/GMT.

Do you get the date via `{{var order.created_at}}`? This seems to return UTC time.

I do not know how to fix it; I just had the same issue and have posted my question here: [Order Confirmation email: How to get order date with correct store timezone?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242605/order-confirmation-email-how-to-get-order-date-with-correct-store-timezone)