# Order Confirmation email: How to get order date with correct store timezone?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email, timezone

If I include the order date in my order confirmation email template via ...

```
Order Date: {{var order.created_at}}
```

..., the resulting order confirmation emails contain the order date in UTC/GMT time. I would prefer the date to be shown in the timezone configured for the store. How to do that?

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Comment: No - the entire task (with this subtask) was taken over by a remote colleague. I do not know if or how he fixed it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The **Timezones** are configured par **website** and not per storeview, so you can set them for the website who contain all the storeviews.

> Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Locale Options > Timezone >
>   GMT (UTC)

Comment: Thanks @prince; I had the correct timezone set in that place already. We operate multiple websites; timezones are set appropriately in the websites. Sorry for confusing the wording. Order time in email templates is still shown in UTC.